# how to find the posterior mode in BRugs

Tags: r, winbugs

I am trying to use the R package "BRugs" to implement Gibbs sampler, however the functions that produce summary posterior stats, such as samplesStats(), only returns the mean and the median. Is it possible to extract the posterior mode?

Comment: If you've saved the MCMC output (the raw MCMC samples -- you might need to specify in the call to BRugs that you want these saved ...?), then you can find an approximate mode using `density()`. That is, `density(samples)$x[density(samples)$y == max(density(samples)$y)]`. If there's more than one parameter you want to estimate the mode for, arrange the samples in an array and use `apply` with the code above.

Comment: or `dd <- density(samples); dd$x[which.max(dd$y)]`

Answer (score 2):

The `samplesSample` function will give you the full MCMC, to illustrate, using the example in the `BRugs` help file...

```
###    Step by step example:    ###
library("BRugs") # loading BRugs

## Prepare the example files in a temporary directory
exfiles <- dir(options()$OpenBUGSExamples, pattern="^Rats.*txt$", full.names=TRUE)
ok <- file.copy(exfiles, tempdir())

## Now setting the working directory to the temporary one:
oldwd <- setwd(tempdir())

## some usual steps (like clicking in WinBUGS):
modelCheck("Ratsmodel.txt")          # check model file
modelData("Ratsdata.txt")            # read data file
modelCompile(numChains=2)            # compile model with 2 chains
modelInits(rep("Ratsinits.txt", 2))  # read init data file
modelUpdate(1000)                    # burn in
samplesSet(c("alpha0", "alpha"))     # alpha0 and alpha should be monitored
modelUpdate(1000)                    # 1000 more iterations ....
```

One can extract the MCMC sample, of say the `alpha` node, and do whatever you like with it via,

```
alpha0<-samplesSample("alpha0")
hist(alpha0)
```

[image]